Inquiry about Transit visa for Turkey
I am a Ghanaian. I have be granted a UK entry visa. I would be traveling to London next month. I wish to travel by Turkish Airline. I also hold a Ghanaian Service Passport. I would do a layover at Istanbul Airport. My final destination is London. Do I need a Turkish transit visa?

It depends on your itinerary.
TWOV (Transit Without Visa) is allowed for passengers transiting through Ankara (ESB), Antalya (AYT), Istanbul: Metropolitan Area (IST) and Sabiha Gokcen (SAW), or Izmir (ADB) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.
TWOV in Antalya (AYT) does not apply when transiting between terminals 1 and 2.
You can check by inputting full details of your trip into the IATA website.

To confirm: TWOV only applies when one isn't doing self transfers, correct?

@ave Correct...
